# php gRPC connections

Tags: php, grpc, http2

I have a question I can't seem to find the answer to.
We are building a gRPC microservice in Go, to serve our main application written in PHP. I am running some tests on one of the functions now, to see the performance.

My results indicate that setting up the connection takes about 2 seconds, but after that, each call takes less than a microsecond.

How does it work in a real-life application? Does it open one shared connection that is kept alive for a while, or does each request to our application have to open its own connection to the service?

If each request has to open its own connection, is it possible to get around this to get rid of the overhead that comes with establishing a new connection?

Comment: Wrote one in php, was very disappointed about Its complexity, first connection is always slow.

Comment: php are meant to work this way while in other non-blocking languages can be run after requests end so php will always reset on every new request

Comment: Had a look at the gRPC and it appears it is done via streaming, which means that you get the result of starting to stream quickly, but that does not mean it’s the final result of streaming all the data through it. As usual with streams it depends on the amount of data being streamed, so if it’s small and can be transferred within initial packet size - then sure, it will be quick. The larger the volume of data - the more time it will require for it to be transferred, aggregated on the the end, processed and so on.

Comment: with PHP what you want is to use swoole or openswoole extension -> then you can setup GRPC connection pooling: https://openswoole.com/docs/grpc/client-pool-constructor

Answer (score 3):

What you need is called connection pool.

I found this PR https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/15426 after a short search on Google, but I am not sure if it is actually for pooling connections.

If you get able to create connections polls, you may just pick up one available connection and use for your request.

[EDITED]

I just found something that may work for your needs:

https://github.com/swoole/swoole-src#the-simplest-example-of-a-connection-pool

If you follow the example of the Redis connection pool you will be able to make a gRPC connection pool.

Answer (score 1):

The latest php-grpc extension will keep your connections around and re-use them between requests.
Those are called "persistent" connections. A previous connection can be re-used if the set of parameters given to the connection constructor are exactly the same.

Source: php-grpc documentation: https://grpc.github.io/grpc/php/class_grpc_1_1_channel.html

> By default, the underlying grpc_channel is "persistent". That is, given the same set of parameters passed to the constructor, the same underlying grpc_channel will be returned.